# prevent warn message on window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

HI I am working on rails application. I am using "window.onbeforeunload" property to detect unsaved changes in the page. Its working fine.

I am also using jquery-rails autocomplete gem to autocomplete text input just like Stackoverflow does. I want to use auto-complete option not to populate the text field but to let the user know that the value he is inserting in, is already added by some user and when user will click on that option user will be redirected to that page.

e.g consider scenario you are asking a question on on stack overflow. If you typed in something and you click on any other link on page it warns you about unsaved changes. I am doing the same. Now when stack overflow will auto-complete my question I want to click on the one of the option suggested by it & wants to go that question directly. But "window.onbeforeunload" property warns me before redirecting to the desired page. I want to bypass the warn message for that particular scenario. How to do this?

Comment: The "property" can't warn you, only some function that displays a warning. Since this is your own application, just don't call that function - stop listening to `onbeforeunload`. Or am I missing something in your description?

Answer (score 0):

Run this script when you don't want the warning...

```
$(window).off("beforeunload");
```

I've just had to do the same myself with a save button that submits a form.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my aceppted answer here: [user-unfriendly onbeforeunload / onunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627090/user-unfriendly-onbeforeunload-onunload/8627124#8627124) I believe it will do what you want. Basically you can overwrite your `onbeforeunload` when the user clicks the auto-complete link. If `onbeforeunload` doesn't return anything, the warning message won't pop up.